# как сделать рамку и подпись к ней?

Tags: android

Как сделать вот такую рамку с текстом вверху. чтобы она была по размеру содержимого ?
в интернете нашел только рамку поля для ввода.

[image: 1]

---

я делал вот такую рамку к RelativeLayout.

На неё добавить текст - будет идеально[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Этот виджет называется `TextInputLayout` в xml можно добавить так:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textField"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/label">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

данный виджет поддерживает много разных стилей таких например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если я правильно вас понял, то вы ищете такое поле:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

которое добавляется через xml в разметку активности:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/outlinedTextField"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/label"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

вся суть изменений находится в этой строке:

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
```

которая отвечает за стиль вашего виджета. Более подробную информацию можно прочитать на [странице документации материал дизайна](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-fields#outlined-text-field)

Comment: увы тут текст показывается только когда поле активно

Comment: там еще хинт можно добавить, и будет постоянно показывать, это именно тот виджет который вы ищете